# Is there necessarily a common element to a sets of subsets

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that you have $2007$ sets, each consisting of $40$ elements, such that each of them has only one common element with any other. Is there necessary a common element belonging to all sets?

I'm sure that answer is yes and even trying to prove more general statement -- if there are $(N+2)$ $N$-elements sets then each of them has one common element with any other if and only if there exists a common element to all of them.

Sketch of proof -- by induction.

Base of induction for $N=2$ is obvious.

Now suppose that you have $N+1$ sets with no common element (by common I mean belonging to all).
$$J_1=(i_1,\ldots,i_N)$$
$$J_2=(i_1,j_2,\ldots,j_N)$$
$$J_3=(i_2,j_2,k_3,\ldots,k_N)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$J_N=(i_{N-1},j_{N-1},k_{N-1},\ldots,z_N)$$
$$J_{N+1}=(i_N,j_N,k_N,\ldots,z_N)$$

It is intuitively clear that it isn't possible to add $J_{N+2}$ set because it would have more than one in common with at least one of those, but how to deduce it rigorously? Or is there an easier way to solve the original problem?

Comment: Question for clarification: Why can it not be that $J_3=(i_1,k_2\ldots k_N)$? That way it would have exactly one common element with $J_1$ and $J_2$.

Comment: @lulu: I believe the question is saying that each set has exactly one element in common with every other set. So your set $S_3$ would need to contain one element that is also in $S_1$.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. For example for $N=3$ there are five sets $\{1,2,3\}, \{1,5,7\}, \{1,4,6\},\{4,5,2\},\{4,7,3\}$, violating it.

Comment: @Shinja  I agree, I misread the question initially.

Comment: @Shinja: Yes, it can. So I think that my representation completely fails with that possibility.

Comment: You can correct your statement by letting the number of sets grow faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $J_1,\cdots,J_{2007}$ be your sets.  Suppose that $J_1=\{a_1,\cdots,a_{40}\}$.  We can partition $\{1,\cdots,2007\}$ as follows:
$$
X_i=\{j\geq 2:a_i\in J_j\}.
$$
This is a partition because every pair of $J_k$'s have *exactly* one element in common.  One of these sets has at least $51$ elements because $\frac{2007-1}{40}=50.15$.  Suppose, wlog, that it is $X_1$.

If $X_1=\{2,\cdots,2007\}$, then we are done.  Therefore, suppose wlog that $2007\not\in X_1$ and that $2,\cdots,52\in X_1$  In other words, $a_1\not\in J_{2007}$ and $a_1\in J_i$ for $i=1,\cdots,52$.  For $j=1,\cdots,52$, consider $J_j\cap J_{2007}$.  Each of these intersections must consist of a single element and be distinct (if not, two of the $J_j$'s would share more than one element).  This, however, is impossible because $J_{2007}$ has only $40$ elements, not $52$.

In general, if you have $M$ sets of $N$ elements, you need $\frac{M-1}{N}>N-1$ to make this argument work.